# Error while Data Ingestion from SFTP to GCS or BigQuery using Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, sftp, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to move CSV files in SFTP folder to GCS using Data Fusion. But I am unable to do it and throwing below error:

Here are the properties of both FTP and GCS plugins. Surprisingly, I could see the data in PREVIEW mode in all the stages but when I try to deploy the pipeline it fails. I tried using CSVParser as well as a TRANSFORM in between source(FTP) and sink (GCS). Still it shows the same error. I am using FTP plugin in Hub with version 3.0.0. Please help me to solve it.

[image]

And the error is as below, when I try to deploy the pipeline, eventhough Preview Data I was able to see the data.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if your FTP plugin is the same as the one indicated by data fusion? ref: [ftp-plugins](https://github.com/data-integrations/ftp-plugins)?

Comment: Also, what configurations are you using inside your plugins? can you also share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the Pipeline execution engine from SPARK to MAPREDUCE in Data Fusion. Now it is working.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to find a solution to your issue. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have dig a lot on this, I found that this plugins have issues when running [ftp-plugins](https://github.com/data-integrations/ftp-plugins), so at the moment you can't do much on it. Fortunately, there are workarounds for this. To name a few here are some:

- You can use an old version ( Dataproc image to 1.5/1.3 ) as indicated on the public case that also makes reference to this issue. For more details about this case, you can check the link for the issue, [SFTP Source fails when deployed (SftpExecption) but not in preview](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217049303). Don't forget to upvote and leave a comment too.
- Another way is to use `SFTPCopy` plugin (once you pick up from the hub it should appear under `Conditions and Actions`). So you will be able to pick up  the file from your SFTP into a local path and the use Source `FILE` to continue with the processing of your file. There is a small guide on [Reading from SFTP and writing to BigQuery](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1162707191/Reading+from+SFTP+and+writing+to+BigQuery)
- This one is a bit extreme but you can also use a different workflow management platform like [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) for file processing.